# How to append to one of the existing dropdown options in select2?

Tags: javascript, jquery, select, dropdown, jquery-select2

I need to build a dropdown functionality that allows users to:
1. autocomplete (based on certain existing values)
2. allows to add a completely new option if the current options are not suitable.

I figured that select2 provides an easy implementation for the dropdown with autocomplete and I am currently using it. However, there are 2 problems: 
1. I want to be able to append the current dropdown option with some custom text which is not working
2. If I start off with the custom text and want to insert the dropdown later (using the auto complete). That also does not work.

Is there a way to customize the autocomplete functionality in a way i want to you use it?
Are there any other jQuery based alternatives that could help me do this?

(I have also tried using tags: true, but that is hacky and does not really work the way i want it to).

Current code:

```
<select id="subject" name="subject" class="gwp-combo-box>
  <option value="option1">Java</option>
  <option value="option2">javascript</option>
</select>

$(".gwp-combo-box").select2({}); //also tried tags: true
```

Comment: https://select2.github.io/examples.html#tokenizer check is this what u want,tokenizer supports multi-select and auto add new options

Answer (score 0):

is it look like this? run and check

```js
$("#subject").select2({
  tags: true,
  tokenSeparators: [',', ';']
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.3/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.3/js/select2.min.js"></script>
<select id="subject" name="subject" class="gwp-combo-box" multiple="multiple">
  <option>Java</option>
  <option>javascript</option>
  <option>jquery ui</option>
</select>
```

Comment: I had tried this out and it is the closest thing I could find to what I wanted, however, upon editing it does not let you edit the existing value, rather creates 2 tags: eg.

Comment: I had tried this out and it is the closest thing I could find to what I wanted, however, upon editing it does not let you edit the existing value, rather creates 2 tags: eg.
intended: [java] ==> [javascript]
actual: [java] ==> [java][script] 

I finally ended up using JQueryAutoComplete and JQueryUI to build what I wanted.